# difference between connected domain and bounded domain

Tags: general-topology, functions

what is the difference between connected domain and bounded domain? I am not able to understand their respective definitions which i found on the internet

Comment: To understand those concepts requires some point-set topology notions.

Comment: Connectedness is topological property where as boundedness is not. Take function 1/x  in (0,1)....

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: For example, set $ (0,1)\cup (1,2)$ is bounded but not connected.

Comment: For above example consider identity function. For 1/x in (0,1), range is $(1,\infty)$ which is connected but not bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not exactly know your context, let's assume your domain is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, equipped with the Euclidean norm.

**Connectedness**: There a different notions of connectedness, but a simple one is [*path-connectedness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness). Informally, a set is simply connected if any two points within the set can be connected by a continuous curves that entirely lies within the set. *Very informally*: A domain could be visualized by islands in the sea: A domain that is not connected would correspond to several islands - an ant cannot walk from one island to the other without getting wet, which illustrates the non-connectedness! A connected domain would correspond to a single island, no matter how its specific shape and size are.

**Boundedness**: On the other hand, a set is *bounded* if there exists some bound $M>0$ such that for every point $x$ in the set the norm is bounded by $M$, i.e. $\|x\| < M$. *Informally*: A domain is bounded if the distance between any two points cannot exceed a maximum. Given a sufficiently large sphere, you can fit the bounded domain completely inside the sphere. On the other hand, you can never find a sphere large enough to contain an unbounded domain.

- a water bottle defines a bounded domain in $\mathbb R^3$: it will entirely fit into a sphere with radius $>$ 1 meter (to be one the safe side). The distance between any two points cannot exceed a certain distance (which is probably slightly more than the height of the bootle).
- In real life, unbounded domains are hard to find. If we could guess that the universe was infinite, it would be an example for an unbounded domain: No matter how large you set a threshold, you could always find a star that is even further away from our sun. In mathematics, unbounded domains in $\mathbb R^n$ contain a sequence whose norm diverges to $\infty$. A simple example is the interval $[0,\infty)$, which is unbounded: For *every* threshold $M$ it contains numbers whose distance from $0$ is larger than $M$.

Connectedness and boundedness are completely unrelated properties. However, often (e.g. in the context of PDEs, ...) both of them are imposed on domains.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you help me understand it with an example? The picture is still not clear to me